# Is there a way to make a "Undetectable Iframe Code"

Tags: php, javascript, iframe

For example, if this code is on any page:

```
<script>
if (top.location != location) {
     alert("In A Frame");
}
</script>
```

It will display an alert.

I need an HTML, Javascript, Php etc. that when you iframe a page with the script above, it will not trigger the alert.

My question how to break the IF statement in the iframe. (or is that possible without scraping all the website and remove it with php code)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may interest you ...
https://www.owasp.org/images/0/0e/OWASP_AppSec_Research_2010_Busting_Frame_Busting_by_Rydstedt.pdf

Answer (score 1):

```
window.alert = function(){return null;};
```

This will disable alert() in IE/FF. May be you can do this in your script

Comment: yeah, thanks !! but that was just an example, what if he done other things than the alert().